# What are best practices for neo4j server plugin development?

Tags: neo4j

I was able to get the example plugins installed on my server using these docs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html

Now I want to develop my own plugins but I'm not sure how to debug and unit test them. Where can I read more about this and best practices for server plugin development?

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your plugin just as simple java project, testing the plugins is easy, just instantiate them in a unit-test and pass the Node, GraphDatabaseService and parameters to the plugin method and inspect the results.

Answer (score 1):

my plugin:

```
package ru.a360.neo4j.plugins;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.*;
import org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Representation;
import org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ValueRepresentation;
import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Description("An extension to the Neo4j Server for find routes between two nodes")
public class WarmUp extends ServerPlugin
{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WarmUp.class.getName());

    public WarmUp()
    {
    }

    @Name("warm_up")
    @Description("Warm up all nodes and relationships")
    @PluginTarget(GraphDatabaseService.class)
    public Representation warmUp(@Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb)
    {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int relCount = 0;
        int nodesCount = 0;
        GlobalGraphOperations ggo = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb);
        for (Node n: ggo.getAllNodes())
        {
            for (String prop: n.getPropertyKeys())
            {
                n.getProperty(prop);
            }
            nodesCount++;
        }
        for (Relationship rel: ggo.getAllRelationships())
        {
            for (String prop: rel.getPropertyKeys())
            {
                rel.getProperty(prop);
            }
            relCount++;
        }
        logger.info("warmup;" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) / 1000.0 );
        return ValueRepresentation.string("WARMED UP " + nodesCount + " NODES AND " + relCount + " RELATIONSHIPS");
    }
}
```

There is new string in main/java/META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin:

```
ru.a360.neo4j.plugins.WarmUp
```

I want to write test (test/java/ru/a360/neo4j/plugins/TestNeo.java) like this:

```
package ru.a360.neo4j.plugins;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestNeo {

    @Before
    public void prepareTestData()
    {
    }

    @After
    public void destroyTestDatabase()
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest1()
    {
    }
}
```